# How to remove the base path from the full path using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, str-replace

I have full path ( using "%%~fl" or %%~l )

```
E:\Documents\Windows-Bash\CheckModels\SB3\models\TEST3\Cerus\Modbridge\Core\g-221.mdl
```

My base path ( according to %~dp0 ) is:

```
E:\Documents\Windows-Bash\CheckModels\SB3\
```

How can I extract:

```
models/TEST3/Cerus/Modbridge/Core/g-221.mdl
```

To search for it inside a text file.

My batch script is like follows:

```
echo off

set DataBase=E:\Documents\Windows-Bash\CheckModels\SB3\DB\trackassembly_init.lua
set AddModel=models_present.txt
set MisModel=models_missing.txt
set BasePath=%~dp0
set Model

dir /a-d /b /s *.mdl > %AddModel%

for /F "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%AddModel%"') do (
  set Model=%%~l 
  :: ?[1] Process the %Model% so it becomes "models/TEST3/Cerus/Modbridge/Core/g-221.mdl"
  :: ?[2] IF (not found %Model% in the contents of %DataBase% ) THEN
  :: ?[2]    echo Model > MisModel ( Append missing file )
  :: ?[2] END
)

del %AddModel%

echo End
timeout 25
```

How can I replace the pseudo-code in ?[1] and ?[2] with the real thing ?
I can easily convert the string using C/C++, but I do not need additional files. Is there a way the whole thing to be converted to C/C++ ?

Comment: You seem to be confused about the terminology here.  Bash is a Unix shell; it certainly exists in a Windows port as well, but the code you are showing is definitely not bash code.  I edited your question to fix this apparent confusion.

Comment: Yes, maybe. It's a "BAT" file as of Windows BATCH. A file containing dos commands telling the windows what to do... I will may be try to do the whole thin in C++ instead, but I thought that this way is more clean as is ...

Comment: You can use the set command to do string replacement to remove the partial path of where the batch file is to your file name.

Comment: I guess what Magoo have posted below, but somehow I cannot get it to work .. Sorry  Squashman for the stupid question, but how should I do that ?

Comment: Already made is with C++ and a batch. Yhe batch call the C++ app and done ...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "basepath=u:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%basepath%"
for /F "tokens=*" %%l in ('dir /a-d /b /s *.mdl ') do (
 set "Model=%%~l"
 call set "relpath=%%model:*%basepath%\=%%"
 call set "relpath=%%relpath:\=/%%"
 CALL echo %%relpath%% FOR %%l
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

Note positioning of quotes to ensure value assigned does not include stray trailing spaces in the sourcecode (difficult to find if they exist)

`basepath` is the relative root for the directory scan. Change to suit yourself - I used a directory that suits my system.

The `call` executes a `set` command with the single-% variable substituted.

set "var1=%var2:string1*=string2%"

sets `var1` to the value of `var2`, with the characters up to and including `string1` replaced by `string2`

Comment: It does not work on Windows 7.

"for /F "tokens=*" %%l in ('dir /a-d /b /s *.mdl ') do" outputs the same file every iteration

_echo %%l
_set "Model=%%l"
  _call echo %Model% >> %LogModel%
  _call set "Relpath=%%Model:%BasePath%*=%%"
  _call echo . >> %LogModel%
  _call echo %Relpath% >> %LogModel%
  _call echo . >> %LogModel%
  _call echo . >> %LogModel%

When I print the model in every iteration is giving me the same file and in %LogModel% i get the exact same file. 

On the other hand "echo %%l" prints what is it supposed to ..